# Validation does not work if its in ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I have a simple page with validating the field, something like this:
`employee.html` and its validating the field but if I have added the same code and called the same page using ng-include the validating is not working

`without ng-include` validate works:

```
 <form name="form" class="form-horizontal" ng-validate="create(data)" novalidate>
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
           <div class="form-group">
               <label for="" class="col-xs-6 control-label">First Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-xs-6">
                     <input name="first_name" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="data.first_name" placeholder="First name" ng-required="true">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="form.$submitted && form.first_name.$error.required">Enter first name.</div>
                  </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

`with ng-include` validate does not works:

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="container">
     ....................
     ..................
     <ng-include src="employee.html"></ng-include>         
</div>
```

my question is: how can I make the validation works within ng-include?

Comment: I think it's related to the fact that `ng-include` creates it's own scope, but I need more context(fiddle would be great).

Comment: Is the validation the only thing that does not work?

Comment: yes validation the only thing that does not work

Comment: I tried and it works

Comment: can you post what you tried?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/whisher/48300c5718325fe56315

Comment: Think it's scope, as @Rasalom said. The include has a different scope from that `create(application)` and then it is not called and the rest won't work. Don't you have errors in console?

Comment: ng-include create a new scope but form is in the scope so ...may be the problem is manage the data but with the validation there is no troubles

Comment: seems like ur `form.$submitted` is not working please double check it, ng-include create a child scope , but ur ng-include should have access to the parent scope. i think the problem is in `form.$submitted`

Comment: @KalhanoToressPamuditha: you are right I think so too `form.$submitted` is not working how do i debug or what do i need to fix?

Comment: @MiguelRoxo: no errors in the console

Comment: remove the `form.$submitted` and check its working or not

Comment: @AbuHamzah I've updated the gist with a simple directive you can also get the data and the validation works !

Comment: @Whisher: thanks I will take a look, appreciate all

Answer (score 0):

yes your `$submitted` is not working `angular version 1.3`. if you need to show the message if only form is submit then you can keep a variable to detect whether the form is submitted or not.

to do that

in controller test function

```
$scope.create = function(data) {
     $scope.formSubmitted = true;
}
```

in validation message use `formSubmitted` instead of `$submitted`

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="formSubmitted && form.first_name.$error.required">E..
```

here is the working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yR6Z0T4dPgg6cUhgfGj2)

---

**But if you are using angular 1.3 or later version**

angular introduce a `$submitted` in angular 1.3.x and may be your trying with a older angular version, upgrading angular will solve your problem.

here is the [Changes of the 1.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-13) - please check the

> new feature: Add new $submitted state to forms

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="form.$submitted && form.first_name.$error.required">Enter first name.</div>
```

here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y0z26l2eMJkGcfHoL2zB?p=preview)

Comment: @AbuHamzah I updated my answer please have a look :)

Comment: I'm using `AngularJS v1.2.23`... will take a look more detail

Comment: yes if you are working `1.2 version` then you have to do something like i suggest in first part, or if you can upgrade the angular version then you can use `$submitted`

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap validation in ui like that

```
<form name="personalinformation">

<label for="fname">  First Name<span style="color:red" ng-show="personalinformation.firstname.$error.required">*</span></label>  
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="" placeholder="First    Name" ng-model="PerInfo.FirstName" required name="firstname">

</form>
```

and if you validation by angular you can create validationFunction and ng-click pass the value of text or other element in controller.If input type is false then you cal fill value in ng-show="true"

Answer (score 0):

Use `<ng-form></ng-form>` instead of `<form></form>`